# Remove right click menu fade (macOS)

Tags: macos, macos-sierra

I have an incurable issue with animations on OSX so I was wondering how one could turn this one off.

The right click menu has a fade animation. In particular this means a new right click menu won't open until the animation is done. Examples:

[image: ex 1]

[image: ex 2]

I'm right-clicking on the other item to dismiss the already-opened right click menu. But it waits a decade for the first one to fade before the second one opens. Can I shorten or remove this delay somehow?

Comment: Are you confusing 'decade' with 'half a second'... or are you seeing something on-screen that's not apparent in your gifs? I can't see anything wrong in that behaviour.

Comment: I was hoping that there would be some way to make the transition instant (no animation) but after some searching, I don't think it is possible...

Comment: won't kill the anim, but if you hold your right click initially for about 0.5s or so, the menu doesn't stay when you let go. Might be an alternative working method...

Comment: Thanks, that's a neat workaround! Could you post that as an answer?

Comment: Sure, can do, if you're satisfied with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments - though this is not strictly 'an answer to the question' it is a potential workaround/alternative paradigm...

Rather than 'fast' right-clicking, if you hold your right-click for perhaps half a second or more - of course, longer if you need to actually read the drop-menu - then when you let go, the menu will just vanish again, leaving you clear to just click something else rather than 'waste a click' dismissing the first menu.

Once you get used to this, then the animation itself becomes a non-issue, because it's done & over with before you even reach your next clickable item.